# Правила .htaccess и регулярные выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache

Правильное правило?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?c=profile&n=$1 [L]
```

Для получения из

> `http://localhost/index.php?c=profile&n=kz001`

этого

> `http://localhost/kz001`

Comment: Может наоборот?

Из этого

    http://localhost/kz001

вот это

    http://localhost/index.php?c=profile&n=kz001

Comment: дело в том что у меня мак и мамп стоит, а доступа по фтп у меня нету, я отдаю человеку он проверяет все и заливает.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения из

```
http://localhost/index.php?c=profile&n=kz001
```

этого

```
http://localhost/kz001
```

будет работать такое правило:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=profile&n=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

**upd:**

Обратное:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ http://localhost/index.php?c=profile&n=$1
```

При заходе на `localhost/abc1` будет давать `localhost/index.php?c=profile&n=abc1`,
при заходе на `localhost/index.php` - будет оставлять index.php. Если так не надо, то `\w+` на `.*` меняем и всё.

Ещё раз ответ в соответствии с последним комментарием:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ?c=profile&n=$1 [L]
```

Вот так, если вы пройдёте по `http://localhost/kz001`, то без редиректа увидите то, что по ссылке `/index.php?c=profile&n=kz001`.

Comment: при запросе на http://localhost/kz001, говорит что страница не существует. :(

Comment: это потому что вам нужно обратное преобразование, как и писал @mantigatos

Comment: @ola_sh? ну да, это другая, обратная задача. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Ребят перепробывал все, не работает, наверное я не правильно объяснил.
Мне нужно получить ЧПУ, я не хочу преобразовывать, пусть будет доступно и так:
http://localhost/index.php?c=profile&n=abc
и так:
http://localhost/abc

Обычный рерайт, 2 раза раньше делал с помощью сервиса, сейчас он не работает. :(

Comment: @ola_sh, ещё раз апдейт ответа.

Answer (score 0):

рерайт может и правильный, но:

1. включен ли mod_rewrite на конечном сервере ?
2. разрешено ли использовать .htaccess ?
3. разрешено ли менять рерайты посредством .htaccess ?
4. попробуйте так: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?c=profile&n=$1 [L]`